# Steps to write my own general equilibrium model in MATLAB

Tags: econometrics, matlab

I'm facing a challenge: writing my own general equilibrium model in MATLAB. I would like to ask for:

1. the basic needed knowledge in mathematics
2. the basic needed knowledge in programming

with references if possible.

I'm a master's degree student in economics, but I'm willing to put in the necessary efforts to achieve my aim. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too broad of a question to be answerable. Do you want some references for DSGE models?

Answer (score 2):

The basic knowledge in mathematics has nothing to do with whether you will be writing code or not. Haven't you been taught Dynamic General Equilibrium in your Master programme? Stochastic Difference Equations, linear approximation, on top of the usual Analysis employed in Economics.

Also, the "basic knowledge in programming" is already specified by you: knowing how to write code in Matlab.

A comprehensive companion for such an endeavor could be

**Burkhard Heer & Alfred Maussner "Dynamic General Equilibrium Modeling", 2009, 2nd ed., Springer.**

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own :) Even if you try, still start with looking at what others did already. Two most popular packages are Dynare and IRIS

[Wolker Wieland](http://www.macromodelbase.com/) maintains a database of most popular DSGE models.

You need to be good in optimization, differential equations and MATLAB.